# identify if there is image on the UIImageview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am having trouble on identifying if there is an image on the UIImageView.

First of all, i have a static table with uiimageview inside.
when user press new page or load the data, they both proceed to the same static table.

But now i want the uiimageview on the new page could show some image placeholder to tell the user can insert pic there. However for the old page with image data, i want to the placeholder to disappear when there is image inside the UIImageView.

How can i do that? I am using the code below to load the data;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   self.set11.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.role valueForKey:@"set1"]];
    self.set111.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.role valueForKey:@"set1"]];
     self.topview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.role valueForKey:@"toppic"]];}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
if(imageView.image){
   //image in UIIMageView
}else{
   //No image !!!
}
```

in your case

```
self.set11.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.role valueForKey:@"set1"]];
if(self.set11.image){
 //image in UIIMageView
}else{
 //No image !!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(self.set11.image)
{
//image is already there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check like this :-

```
if(yourImageView.image != nil)
{
     //Image in image View
}
else
{

    // image Not Found

}
```